# Will the UIStackView work?

Tags: ios, iphone, uistackview

Will the UIStackView work with iPhone all versions?

Comment: Yes, It will work with all iPhone devices having iOS version 9.x except iPhone 4.

Comment: UIStackView can be used only with iOS 9.0 and above. and iPhone 4 doesn't support iOS9. So you can't use for your phone.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't know this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can read about UIStackView here. It requires minimum iOS 9.0, read here  [https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIStackView_Class_Reference/](http://here). 
Also you can check all device which support iOS9 from this link 
[iOS 9 supported devies](https://www.apple.com/ios/whats-new/#compatibility)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.